# Adding a link to an image variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink, popupwindow

I have a popup window that links to a facebook page if they click the link, but I want to add the facebook logo that also leads to the page when clicked. I have the image appearing, but I can't figure out how to link it to the same place.

```
function windowProp(text) {


newWindow = window.open('','newWin','width=300,height=200');
var img1 = '<img src="FacebookImage.jpg" alt="logo" width="40" height="40"/>';

newWindow.document.write(text);
newWindow.document.write(bonusText);
newWindow.document.write(img1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image should be nested in the link

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="FacebookImage.jpg" alt="logo" width="40" height="40"/> </a>
```